# Saving a BigQuery view with dynamic SQL using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Tags: google-bigquery

I created an SQL query using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE on BigQuery, in order to count rows on of all tables in my data-set.

I would need to save this as a view so I can use it in another query for reporting. However, BigQuery does no allow saving my query as a view.

```
declare query string default (
    select string_agg(
                   array_to_string(
                           ["SELECT '",
                               table_name,
                                   "' as table_name, " ||
                                   "count(*) as row_count from my_data_set.",
                               table_name, ' union all'],
                       ''),
                   ' ')

    from my_data_set.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE substr(query, 1, length(query) - length(' union all'))
```

Saving this as a view will return a `Only SELECT statements are allowed in view queries` error.

So what is the work around here? How do I get to save this---or its equivalent--for later as a view?

Comment: the only work around here i see is to submit feature request to BigQuery Team - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0 to make scripts work in view

Comment: Good idea @MikhailBerlyant I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
declare dsql string;
declare query string default (
    select string_agg(
                   array_to_string(
                           ["SELECT '",
                               table_name,
                                   "' as table_name, " ||
                                   "count(*) as row_count from my_data_set.",
                               table_name, ' union all'],
                       ''),
                   ' ')

    from my_data_set.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
);

set dsql = 'create or replace view my_data_set.my_view as ' || substr(query, 1, length(query) - length(' union all'));

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dsql;
```

Comment: I hope you are expecting this solution. If not, please let me know, so that I will delete this post !

Comment: Hi, thanks. Though I'm afraid this does not answer the question.

Comment: I am little confused here. As per the question `BigQuery view with dynamic SQL using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, I believe, the answer is appropriate. Yes, you can change your question as per accepted answer ☹

Comment: The problem is BigQuery won’t allow saving a view that includes `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` which you still use in your proposed solution. I relise now that you made a query that is supposed to be run as a script, which in turn will write the view on my behalf. I didn’t understand that initially and tried to save that as a view. Now I see how it could work and will give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: @Benjamin; thank you. Honestly, you have done all the hard work and I did a very small piece !

Comment: you're right, I've overlooked and misunderstood our approach, my bad. That's a great way to solve the issue and wish I would have thought about it myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

for this particular report, you can use another INFORMATION_SCHEMA table:

```
select table_id,row_count from `project-id.dataset_id.__TABLES__`
```

it's already calculated

till now you can not create a view using `execute immediate`  as far as I know

sorry the last sentence needed correction

Comment: :O A shortcut! How didn't I find this in documentation? Thanks a ton.